# Memory error writing small PySpark DataFrame to parquet

Tags: pyspark, out-of-memory

I'm having problems saving a transformed Spark DataFrame using PySpark.

My original data is split across 90 csv.gz files, resulting in a 500MM rows DataFrame. If I try to write.parquet() it without transformations, I succeed. But I fail to do so after applying some filters that actually reduce the DF size to 300k rows.

More interestingly, if I add a final filter to reduce it even further to 10k rows, then write.parquet() works.

I would like to understand why I'm getting an OOM error with a 300k rows DF when the 500MM doesn't face any issues and what can be done to sort this out.

**CODE:**

```
spark = SparkSession \
  .builder \
  .master("local[*]")\
  .appName("Python Spark SQL basic example") \
  .config("spark.driver.memory", "4G") \
  .getOrCreate()

path = r'files'
file_list = g.glob(os.path.join(path, "*.gz")) 

df = spark.read.option("header", "true").csv(file_list)
df.write.parquet("out/originalDF.parquet")                  #500MM rows SUCCESS!

#some transformations here: 5 new columns, filter rows

df.write.parquet("out/intermediateDF.parquet")              #300k rows FAILED!

df = df.filter(col('symbol')=='foo')
df.write.parquet("out/finalDF.parquet")                     #10k rows SUCCESS!
```

**ERROR:**

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o162.parquet.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted.
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: 
Task 48 in stage 4.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: 
Lost task 48.0 in stage 4.0 (TID 228) (DESKTOP-DASDF23.home executor driver):
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

Comment: Did you find what was the reason for happening this ? I am facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure that `.config("spark.driver.memory", "4G")` cannot be set inside the Spark App itself. It's too late to do that as the App has started with memory allocation already set.

Try like this, for example: `$ ./bin/spark-shell --driver-memory 4g`. Or some higher value.